# How to open a CSV file update some rows, columns, delete some rows and save it as another CSV file in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a csv file. I need to open it, delete whole row on basis of a column value, Update few of the column values and save the file as .dat file.
I am using VB.net 2010

Comment: http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to load, remove and update your CSV, for example:

```
Const separator = ","c
Dim csvPath = "C:\Temp\USPresident.csv"
Dim datPath = "C:\Temp\USPresident.dat"
Dim rows = (From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(csvPath)
               Select line.Split(separator)).ToList
' get all lines with specific value ' 
Dim presidentRows = (From cols In rows
               Where cols.Contains("William Howard Taft")).ToList
' remove these lines with Except'
Dim rowsWithoutPresident = rows.Except(presidentRows).ToList
' update some values '
For Each row In rowsWithoutPresident
    row(3) = "test-value"
Next
Dim newLines = (From cols In rowsWithoutPresident
               Select String.Join(separator, cols)).ToArray
IO.File.WriteAllLines(datPath, newLines)
```

Tested with [this csv-file with US-presidents](http://seepeoplesoftware.com/downloads/easytable-free/26-sample-csv-file-of-us-presidents.html).

*[Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) On | [Option Infer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) On | [Option Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) On*